# Как вывести двумерный массив корректно?

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Пусть дано:Заполнить массив  ×  числами от 0 до 2 − 1 в требуемом порядке:А именно сверху вниз от 0 до 4,от 5 до 9 снизу вверх,от 10 до 14 сверху вниз,от 15 до 19-снизу вверх и от 20 до 24 сверху вниз.
Вот мой код,но он не до конца выполняет задачу и выводит цифры от 1 до 25:

```
//заполнить массив
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Array {
public:
    Array();
    void Out();
private:
    static const int n = 5;
    int A[n][n];
};

Array::Array()
{
    int Number = 0;
    const int maxNumber = n * n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int i2 = i;
        if (i % 2)
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++, i2--) {
                A[i2][j] = ++Number;
                A[n - 1 - i2][n - 1 - j] = (maxNumber - Number + 1);
            }

        else
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++, i2--) {
                A[j][i2] = ++Number;
                A[n - 1 - j][n - 1 - i2] = (maxNumber - Number + 1);
            }
    }
}

void Array::Out()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << setw(5) << A[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Array A;
    A.Out();
    return 0;
}
```

Как исправить этот код?Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пойти еще проще, и не ставить условный оператор if в цикл, а запустить 2 цикла.

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            A[j][i] = j + i*n;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i+=2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            A[j][i] = (i + 1) * n - j - 1;
        }
    }
```

А можно без умножений

```cpp
    int num = 0;
    int d = 1;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (;j >= 0 && j < n; j+=d) {
            A[j][i] = num++;
        }
        d = -d;
        j += d;
    }
```

Есть третий вариант

```cpp
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        A[j][i] = j;
    }
    ++i;
    int num = n;
    for (int j = n-1; j >= 0; --j) {
        A[j][i] = num++;
    }

    for (i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            A[j][i] = A[j][i-2] + num;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Хорошо,понял,cпасибо за помощь)